# What does this theorem mean? Kernels and bases

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Theorem** Let $f: U \rightarrow V$ be a linear map, where $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $\Bbb F$ with $n= \dim(U),\ m = \dim(V)$. Let $B$ and $C$ be bases of $U$ and $V$ respectively and $A$ be the matrix of $f$ with respect to these bases.  Let $g: \ ^n\Bbb F \rightarrow \ ^m\Bbb F$ be the map given by $g(u) = A \ .  z$ for all $z \in \ ^n\Bbb F$. If $u_1,\ldots,u_k \in U $ are elements such that $\left\{(u_1)_B,\ldots,(u_k)_B\right\}$ is a basis of $\ker(g)$, then $\left\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\right\}$ is a basis of $\ker(f)$.

What does this Theorem mean? How do I make sense of it!

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does $^n\Bbb F$ mean?

Comment: And what does $(u_i)_B$ mean? By the way, it might help if you told us where you found this theorem...

Comment: @A.P. $(u_i)_B$ is simply the vector of $^n \Bbb{F}$ corresponding to $u_i \in U$ in the basis $B$.

Comment: @Stef $^n\Bbb F$ is simply $\Bbb F^n$

Comment: Oh sorry, no $^n\Bbb F$ is the notation of row space

Comment: And $(u_i)_B$ is the coordinate vector with respect to B

Comment: It is part of my notes for linear transformations

Comment: To me, this simply means that a basis for the kernel of the matrix representation of a linear map gives a basis for the map itself... but frankly this also feels too trivial to me to warrant the moniker of "theorem".